# How can I prove the following formula using semantic equivalences

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi I am trying to prove the following formula using semantic equivalences

$$(p \land q) \to r \;\equiv\; p \to (q \to r )$$

I am thinking maybe to use the implication rule but I am note sure.

Comment: How would a proof by semantic equivalence be much different from a proof of their equivalence using truth tables? Aside from superficial differences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some basic identities to transform the lefthand side.

$$
\begin{align}
(p \wedge q) \to r &\equiv p \to (q \to r) \\
\neg(p \wedge q) \vee r &\equiv   \\
\neg p \vee \neg q \vee r &\equiv  \\
p \to (\neg q \vee r) &\equiv   \\
p \to (q \to r) &\equiv  \\
\end{align}
$$

I'll leave it to you to figure out which rules I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is what I did, please correct me if I am wrong

```
(p ∧ q) ⇒ r ≡ p ⇒ (q ⇒ r )

¬(p ∧ q) v r - implication 

¬p∨¬q∨r - de morgan

p→(¬q∨r)- implication

p→(q→r) - implication
```

Comment: @dan what do you think of the solution above?

Comment: Looks fine to me, just be aware a few of the steps also use rules of associativity: eg $(p \vee q) \vee r \equiv p \vee (q \vee r)$.